# Get Transactions associated with a Recurring Payment Profile in Paypal

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

I have gone through nearly all the question related to Recurring Payment using Paypal and have not found a solution to my problem.

We are implementing a system that is subscription based on a monthly basis (fixed amount). We do not want to store CC details for security reasons, hence we are trying to use Website Payments Pro from Paypal.
Once a user agrees to recurring payments, we are creating a RecurringPaymentProfile for that user and are storing the returned Profile_Id for the user.

Now we need to get information about all the transactions related to this Recurring Profile_Id. This information is available when we login to the Paypal account but this needs to be automated so that the application is aware of all the payments and also of the current subscription of the user.

We have found two methods (possibly) to implement this.
1. IPN (Instant Payment Notification, for this we will have to create a service to listen to notifications, which seems to be cumbersome and is more informational than we require)
2. TransactionSearch (but this returns transactions for the Paypal account and not Profile_Id)

Since we just want to know the transaction history associated with the Recurring Profile and whether this months payment was successful (implying the user is active member), what is the best method to implement this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the [GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails API Operation](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails). This operation will allow you to view a majority of the details associated with a recurring payment profile using a valid `PROFILEID`.

Relevant detail fields you may be interested in:

> **LASTPAYMENTDATE**
> The date of the last successful payment received for
> this profile, in YYYY-MM-DD format.
>
> **LASTPAYMENTAMT**
> The amount of the last successful payment received for this profile.
>
> **FAILEDPAYMENTCOUNT**
> The total number of failed billing cycles for this profile.
>
> **NEXTBILLINGDATE**
> The next scheduled billing date, in YYYY-MM-DD format.
>
> **NUMCYCYLESCOMPLETED**
> The number of billing cycles completed in the
> current active subscription period. A billing cycle is considered
> completed when payment is collected or after retry attempts to collect
> payment for the current billing cycle have failed.

Comment: We have considered using GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails API Operation but should this API be called when a user logs in or as a service ? If we call it when a user logs in we will get the information for only the previous transaction. If a user logs in after 4 months we would have no information for 3 transactions and we are hoping to save details for every transaction in our DB for any references required later on, as a log.

Comment: If you're looking to log each cycle, then you should execute the API operation through a monthly-scheduled task and store the details in your DB accordingly.

Comment: So I guess, the only option to save the log is to write a service or a task, we are looking into using either GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails or implementing the IPN service itself.

Comment: In my opinion, to get an accurate record of each transaction, implementing the IPN service would be your best bet, rather than running a scheduled task and executing the API each month.